# VAEX groupby datetime column and another column

Tags: python, vaex

I have a timeseries of data and I'd like to use VAEX to manipulate it. I need to groupby an integer "species" column and then also bin by minute. I have tried

```
    air_df.groupby(by = [vaex.BinnerTime(air_df["DT"],resolution = "m"),air_df["species"]])
```

but it gives an error "pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Unsupported datetime64 time unit"
It can manage grouping on both columns seperately, but when combined it fails. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Wondering if you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi, Never found a solution within vaex, but to be honest I stopped trying a long time ago. You can create your own column using the base number of minutes since a time of your choice and then group on that as an integer value, but it's extra work that I don't want, especially when pandas resamples by time effortlessly. You can convert back and forth from vaex to pandas so that's the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most elegant workaround is to create a virtual column for grouping with the timestamp at the desired resolution. Some resolutions aren't supported for `groupby`, but this may be resolved by converting back to nanosecond resolution afterwards. For example:

```
air_df['DT_minute'] = air_df['DT'].astype('datetime64[m]')
air_df['DT_minute'] = air_df['DT_minute'].astype('DT_minute[ns]')
air_df.groupby(by = ['DT_minute', 'species']])
```